# how can show error or warning in the page

Tags: php

I have a site in a server.

Because of settings, no error or warning is displaying in the page

How can i change the setting, using .htaccess file

Comment: errors happens in the server software i.e. Apache Or PHP ?

Comment: use phpinfo() and tell us what are the values of display_errors and error_reporting settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, You can add a line to your PHP like so:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','On');  ?>
```

Or add the following lines to your htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

I personally try to stay away from modifying the htaccess file if any part of the site is in production.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this url](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/14/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/) for some handy .htaccess flags.  You can also handle non-startup errors via setting the following within a PHP script (generally at the top):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Where `E_ALL` can also be replaced with a standard [error constant](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).